# MapBox Cluster map not showing clusters

Tags: express, mongoose, mapbox, ejs, geojson

I am new to coding and Trying to build an app that showcase campgrounds in diferrent loctaions. I used a mapbox cluster map in my index.ejs but for some reason I dont seem to be able to display the clusters in the map. At the moment the map is showing up empty and I am getting the following error:

"clusterMap.js:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: campgrounds is not defined" although I am defining the constant 'campgrounds' in my index, prior to linking my clusteMap.js

Here is my index.ejs file:

```
<% layout('layouts/boilerplate')%>
<div id="cluster-map"></div>
<div class="container">
    <h1>All Campgrounds</h1>

    <% for (let campground of campgrounds){%>
        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <%if(campground.images.length) {%>
                        <img class="img-fluid" alt="" src="<%=campground.images[0].url%>">
                        <% }else {%>
                            <img class="img-fluid" alt=""
                                src="https://res.cloudinary.com/douqbebwk/image/upload/v1600103881/YelpCamp/lz8jjv2gyynjil7lswf4.png">
                            <% } %>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">
                            <%= campground.title %>
                        </h5>

                        <p class="card-text">
                            <%= campground.description %>
                        </p>
                        <p class="card-text">
                            <small class="text-muted">
                                <%= campground.location%>
                            </small>
                        </p>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/campgrounds/<%=campground._id%>">View
                            <%=campground.title%>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% }%>
</div>
<script>
    const mapToken = '<%-process.env.MAPBOX_TOKEN%>';
    const campgrounds = <% - JSON.stringify(campgrounds) %>;
</script>

<script src="/javascripts/clusterMap.js"></script>
```

Here is my clusterMap.js:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibmF0YWxpb3ZhbGxlcyIsImEiOiJjbGR1cjFibHIwOGI1M3BwY2hsN2ZvZ21rIn0.X5rVCtxoQuDW3cRvrrr9Ew';
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'cluster-map',
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
center: [-103.59179687498357, 40.66995747013945],
zoom: 3
});

map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());

map.on('load', function () {
// Add a new source from our GeoJSON data and
// set the 'cluster' option to true. GL-JS will
// add the point_count property to your source data.
map.addSource('campgrounds', {
    type: 'geojson',
    // Point to GeoJSON data. This example visualizes all M1.0+ earthquakes
    // from 12/22/15 to 1/21/16 as logged by USGS' Earthquake hazards program.
    data: campgrounds.features,
    cluster: true,
    clusterMaxZoom: 14, // Max zoom to cluster points on
    clusterRadius: 50 // Radius of each cluster when clustering points (defaults to 50)
});

map.addLayer({
    id: 'clusters',
    type: 'circle',
    source: 'campgrounds',
    filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
    paint: {
        // Use step expressions (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-step)
        // with three steps to implement three types of circles:
        //   * Blue, 20px circles when point count is less than 100
        //   * Yellow, 30px circles when point count is between 100 and 750
        //   * Pink, 40px circles when point count is greater than or equal to 750
        'circle-color': [
            'step',
            ['get', 'point_count'],
            '#00BCD4',
            10,
            '#2196F3',
            30,
            '#3F51B5'
        ],
        'circle-radius': [
            'step',
            ['get', 'point_count'],
            15,
            10,
            20,
            30,
            25
        ]
    }
});

map.addLayer({
    id: 'cluster-count',
    type: 'symbol',
    source: 'campgrounds',
    filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
    layout: {
        'text-field': '{point_count_abbreviated}',
        'text-font': ['DIN Offc Pro Medium', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
        'text-size': 12
    }
});

map.addLayer({
    id: 'unclustered-point',
    type: 'circle',
    source: 'campgrounds',
    filter: ['!', ['has', 'point_count']],
    paint: {
        'circle-color': '#11b4da',
        'circle-radius': 4,
        'circle-stroke-width': 1,
        'circle-stroke-color': '#fff'
    }
});

// inspect a cluster on click
map.on('click', 'clusters', function (e) {
    const features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
        layers: ['clusters']
    });
    const clusterId = features[0].properties.cluster_id;
    map.getSource('campgrounds').getClusterExpansionZoom(
        clusterId,
        function (err, zoom) {
            if (err) return;

            map.easeTo({
                center: features[0].geometry.coordinates,
                zoom: zoom
            });
        }
    );
});


map.on('click', 'unclustered-point', function (e) {
    const popUpMarkup = e.features[0].properties.popUpMarkup; // Use 'popUpMarkup' here
    const coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
    const { properties } = e.features[0];
    // const coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();

    while (Math.abs(e.lngLat.lng - coordinates[0]) > 180) {
        coordinates[0] += e.lngLat.lng > coordinates[0] ? 360 : -360;
    }

    new mapboxgl.Popup()
        .setLngLat(coordinates)
        .setHTML(properties.popUpMarkup) // Use properties.popUpMarkup here
        .addTo(map);
});

map.on('mouseenter', 'clusters', function () {
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
});
map.on('mouseleave', 'clusters', function () {
    map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
});
});
```

I also had to directly paste my maptoken in the clusterMap.js because it kept saying mapToken is not define although I am defining it in index.ejs. Is like if none of the information in the index.ejs is been read in my ClusterMap.js.

For reference here is my campground model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('strictPopulate', false);
const Review = require('./review');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ImageSchema = new Schema({
url: String,
filename: String
})

ImageSchema.virtual('thumbnail').get(function () {
return this.url.replace('/upload', '/upload/w_200');
}); //we use a virtual so this is not store on our model or database because it derives 
from information we already have

const opts = { toJSON: { virtuals: true } };

const CampgroundSchema = new Schema({
// type: String,
title: String,
images: [ImageSchema],
geometry: {
    type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Point'],
        required: true
    },
    coordinates: {
        type: [Number],
        required: true
    }
},
price: Number,
description: String,
location: String,
author: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, //giving an id to the author so the author can edit or 
delete
    ref: 'User'
},
reviews: [
    {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Review'
    }
],
}, opts);


CampgroundSchema.virtual('properties.popUpMarkup').get(function () {
return `<strong><a href="/campgrounds/${this._id}">${this.title}</a></strong>
<p>${this.description.substring(0, 20)}...</p>`
});

CampgroundSchema.post('findOneAndDelete', async function (doc) {
if (doc) {
    await Review.deleteMany({
        _id: {
            $in: doc.reviews
        }
    })
}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Campground', CampgroundSchema);
```

And here is my controllers campgrounds.js:

```
const Campground = require('../models/campground');
const mbxGeocoding = require("@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/services/geocoding");
const mapBoxToken = process.env.MAPBOX_TOKEN;
const geocoder = mbxGeocoding({ accessToken: mapBoxToken });
const { cloudinary } = require("../cloudinary");


module.exports.index = async (req, res) => {
const campgrounds = await Campground.find({}).populate('popupText');
res.render('campgrounds/index', { campgrounds })
}

module.exports.renderNewForm = (req, res) => {
res.render('campgrounds/new');
}

module.exports.createCampground = async (req, res, next) => {
const geoData = await geocoder.forwardGeocode({
    query: req.body.campground.location,
    limit: 1
}).send()
const campground = new Campground(req.body.campground);
campground.geometry = geoData.body.features[0].geometry;
campground.images = req.files.map(f => ({ url: f.path, filename: f.filename }));
campground.author = req.user._id;
await campground.save();
console.log(campground);
req.flash('success', 'Successfully made a new campground!');
res.redirect(`/campgrounds/${campground._id}`)
}

module.exports.showCampground = async (req, res,) => {
const campground = await Campground.findById(req.params.id).populate({
    path: 'reviews',
    populate: {
        path: 'author'
    }
}).populate('author');
if (!campground) {
    req.flash('error', 'Cannot find that campground!');
    return res.redirect('/campgrounds');
}
res.render('campgrounds/show', { campground });
}

module.exports.renderEditForm = async (req, res) => {
const { id } = req.params;
const campground = await Campground.findById(id)
if (!campground) {
    req.flash('error', 'Cannot find that campground!');
    return res.redirect('/campgrounds');
}
res.render('campgrounds/edit', { campground });
}

module.exports.updateCampground = async (req, res) => {
const { id } = req.params;
console.log(req.body);
const campground = await Campground.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { ...req.body.campground });
const imgs = req.files.map(f => ({ url: f.path, filename: f.filename }));
campground.images.push(...imgs);
await campground.save();
if (req.body.deleteImages) {
    for (let filename of req.body.deleteImages) {
        await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(filename);
    }
    await campground.updateOne({ $pull: { images: { filename: { $in: 
req.body.deleteImages } } } })
}
req.flash('success', 'Successfully updated campground!');
res.redirect(`/campgrounds/${campground._id}`)
}

module.exports.deleteCampground = async (req, res) => {
const { id } = req.params;
await Campground.findByIdAndDelete(id);
req.flash('success', 'Successfully deleted campground')
res.redirect('/campgrounds');
}
```

I also think maybe there is an issue with how the campground information is been retrieve in terms of format? Like maybe is not in the right GeoJSOn format? Not sure. Thank you.